# Nvidia GTX 260 supports directx 11

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

I have downloaded GPU-Z to check specs more accurate for my video card NVIDIA GTX 260 and it says that it support directx 11. Note this is not the directX of the windows, not checking with dxdiag. Can anyone confirm this? Attached screenshoots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: ... and your question is...?

Comment: It clearly shows it supports DirectX 10 not DirectX 11

Comment: [This](https://www.avforums.com/threads/nvidia-gtx-260-direct-x-11-compatible.1910452/) has a good explanation of the reason GPU-Z indicates DX support the way it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX 11 and 12 have what is known as "feature levels" where they indicate that the driver supports being spoken to using the DirectX 11/12 API, but then can specify what DirectX version "hardware" features are fully supported by the card.

In your case the card supports DirectX 11 Feature Level 10.0, meaning that the card will only function if the game uses only DirectX 10.0 and lower features.

To be clear: that card supports DirectX 10 hardware features only.